# Problem with UIScrollView and UITabBar / UINavigationController

Tags: iphone, uinavigationcontroller, uiscrollview, uitabbar

I created a new ViewController with xib-file and implemented a working (which means that I set the contentSize) ScrollView with an ImageView. But when I then use a TabBar or NavigationController to structure my app, the scrolling won't work anymore.
I'm searching for the error since last week but I can't find it. Can anybody help me, please?
LLAP, CyDummy

Answer (score 0):

I have no clue about the error but I recreated the project with the "Tab Bar Application" template and now it works...